# How to make project exe,how to include all runtime dll files

Tags: visual-c++

How to include the windows runtime dll files in setup project.

without vc++ 6.0 software in the machine the project must execute.

or give me the hint how to make a the project setup(EXE) in vc++ 6.0 ,i am using create installor,

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the project settings to link statically to the C runtime (I assume this is what you mean when you said windows runtime ?).  The static link flags are:

- MultiThreaded static linkage (/MT)
- MultiThreaded debug static linkage (/MTd)

Sorry, been awhile since I used VC6.0, so I had to check the GUI.  You'll find this in project settings, C++ tab, Code Generation combo box, "Use run-time library").

Comment: This is actually unnecessary in VC 6, since MSVCRT.DLL (for version 6) ships with every semi-recent Windows OS. It only (sometimes) makes sense for VC 2005+.

Answer (score 1):

To add to what Cannonade has already said, if you are doing it through Visual Studio, then this can be done through Project Settings->General Page->Use MFC as a static library. This way your created exe will be ready to run on any windows box.