# generate exe file

Tags: visual-c++

i have developed application in visual c++ 6.0,i have do exe of that application,i have done by using icnt.exe(install creator),but when i run my application exe file on other system which does't have the vc++ software it's showing dll files are missing,how could than i downloaded the dll files again it is asking other dll's files.i want run my application without installing vc++ software in windows,how can i solve it,plz help me i'm touble.
How to make Realease build? by default its debug build

thanks for reply.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/657109/how-to-make-project-exe-how-to-include-all-runtime-dll-files/657119#657119

Answer (score 1):

As a wild guess, you have deployed the Debug build, which depends on DLLs that are not allowed to be shipped.

If that is the case, have VC6 create a Release build and deploy that.

You can verify which DLLs are required by your application with the depends.exe utility that came with Visual Studio.

**Edit:** The easiest way to get a release build when ready is to use the Batch Build command from the Build menu.  It will let you pick among all of the known build types in the project, and choose to either build them clean (recommended) or to just bring them up to date.

It is also possible to switch the GUI to default to the Release build instead of Debug. That is the right thing to do if you actually need to run the debugger on the Release build. Note that both builds include debug symbols. The differences have more to do with which runtime libraries are linked, and certain optimizations such as making the `assert()` macro have no effect.

Comment: How to make Realease build? by default its debug build.

Comment: See the Batch Build item in the Build menu. I've been more wordy in my edited answer...